# MismatchSenderId on Django - Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I would like to implement Django-fcm when I try to test it, I was able to install Django FCM everything went successfully.

Here is the error that appears MismatchSenderId.

Here are some illustration screenshots:

[image: The error on postman]

[image: The headers on postaman]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `MismatchSenderId` is thrown when you're using the Server Key from a different project, not associated with the Registration token you're sending the message to (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43244992/4625829)). I'm not familiar with Django, but was there any part in your code that you specified a *Sender ID*? If there was, I'd double check it's value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not specifying the sender ID in my code

Comment: That's odd. Not even a default? Is there even a manifest file there? (Sorry, really not familiar with Django)

Comment: Django makes available a settings file that allows you to configure Firebase Cloud Messaging in this file I put the FCM_APIKEY and FCM_SENDER_ID but when I test the same error appears MismatchSenderId

Comment: Could you try setting the Sender ID to `103953800507`, try to get a new token, and retry sending a message?

Comment: When I try this sender ID with a new token the same error is displayed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I debugged and found out that in the Django project I was not using the right json file. To make sure, you are not adding the wrong json file,
go to the

> firebase console > select your app -> go to settings ->select service
> accounts tab -> select python ->

download the server key json file and add the code mentioned to the settings file.