# Firebase Send Rest API results in MismatchSenderId error

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My objective is to send messages/notifications from a C# web app to Android/iOS device using Firebase Rest API.

I started using this as a reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

I went into the console for the Firebase project and went to Settings > Cloud Messaging, where I got the server key.

I have the result of a onTokenRefresh() and so in Postman I try the following:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=snip
Body:

{
    "to":"snip",
    "data":{
        "Lorem": "ipsum"
    }
}
```

And the response is:

```
"error": "MismatchSenderId"
```

Is this because the token I used in the "to" field belongs to a different app/firebase project? Or am I missing another step?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase MismatchSenderID when Authorization key is my Server key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244901/firebase-mismatchsenderid-when-authorization-key-is-my-server-key)

Answer (score 0):

> *Is this because the token I used in the "to" field belongs to a different app/firebase project?*

Yes. This is probably the issue. If you used a `google-services.json` file from a different project and didn't *authorize* the other project to send to the corresponding token (see my answer about multiple senders [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981412/4625829)), then it would return `MismatchSenderId`.