# Firebase Notification successfully sent via CURL and Firebase console but not received on the device

Tags: android, firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am trying to send a push notification to my android device using legacy app server protocol. The notification was sent successful as per the response but I did not receive anything on my android device. 
I also tried sending a notification using the firebase console and there also it shows successfully sent but again I didn't receive anything.

This problem was discussed in the following answer [Firebase Notification not received on device when sent via cURL/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979235/firebase-notification-not-received-on-device-when-sent-via-curl-php) but I have not made the mistakes addressed in the answers here.

This is the request I made

```
 curl -X POST 
-H "Authorization:key=MyAuthorizationKey" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{ "message": { "notification": { 
                       "title": "FCM Message", 
                        "body": "This is an FCM Message", },
      "to": "MyDeviceToken"}
}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

This is the response I got

```
{"multicast_id":8835070472349844293,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1555418431449800%06445bacf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

My app was not running in the foreground when this request was made. So the notification should be delivered and displayed by google services but this is not happening.

Here is my manifest file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.srishti.elderly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUp"
            android:label="SignUp" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignIn"
            android:label="SignIn" />

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>

        <activity android:name=".Home"
            android:label="Home"></activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my onMessageReceived function

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        Log.d(TAG, "on message received");

        final Context context = this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);


        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("FTest")
                .setContentText("Firebabse notification test")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }
```

Update:

This is the new json I tried sending it with:

```
curl -X POST 
-H "Authorization:key=Authorizationkey" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{ 
     "data": { "title": "FCM Message", "body": "This is an FCM Message" }, 
     "to": "devicetoken"
}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Update:
There was a problem with my device when I ran it on a different one it worked. Thanks.

Comment: which means there is something wrong with the implementation in the application, so we would need to see that code to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Should I post my manifest file code here ? Because the onMessageReceived method will not be called as it is a notification message, should I post that too ?

Comment: If we  are only talking about background notifications, then only really manifest is needed, but it would be good to know if it works when app is open aswell

Comment: What is your device android version ?

Comment: @ismailalaoui it is Android 6.0 (API level 23)

Comment: Are you getting debug inside this method? If No then you are doing something wrong with your configuration on Firebase Console. Also please confirm gradle dependencies you have added in your gradle files and added google-services.json inside app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your are sending message which only works when application is on foreground , to make it works when the application is in background you should use data , try this form :

```
{
  "data": {
      "title":"FCM Message", 
      "Body":"This is an FCM Message"            
  }, 
 "to" : "devicetoken"
}
```

Explanation:

- **notification** - messages that goes directly to Android's Notification tray only if your application is in background/killed or gets delivered to onMessageReceived() method if your app is in foreground.
- **Data payload** - Doesn't matter whether your application is in forground or background or killed, these messages will always be delivered to onMessageReceived() method.

Comment: But shouldn't notifications be delivered even when app is in background ? I think the data field is used when we want to deliver the message in app so that is processed on onMessageReceived method ?

Comment: but as is mentioned in the notification explanation, that notification is delivered to notification tray if it is in background, and my app is in background and not foreground

Comment: Even in foreground it is not being received

Comment: Since you are using onMessageReceived , to get ìt in the background you should use data instead of message

Comment: Can you do a break point to see if the payload is received or not ?

Comment: Yes it is correct I have added is the file as per the instructions, and I tried with data instead of message and it still didn't work.

Comment: see updated new json again, but still didn't get notification

Comment: Did you add a break point to onReceivedMessage to see if you receive the payload or not ?

Comment: It is not even being received after trying it directly from the firebase console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191922/discussion-between-ismail-alaoui-and-srishti77714).